# Error Message: startVideoRecording was called while a camera was streaming images

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm processing a camera image stream .same time I'm trying to record that image stream using video record in flutter how could I achieve this.

```
if (_camera != null && _camera.value.isInitialized && !_camera.value.isRecordingVideo) {
        //video recording sectionm
      _onRecordVideo();
    }
    _camera.startImageStream((CameraImage image) {
    //proccessing images
}
```

Comment: got any solution?

Comment: Have you found any solution for this..?